# Why padding-left does not work in my simple case?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple layout, just two un-ordered list by using `<ul><li>`, with each of them inside a `<div>` .

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="fist-list">
        <ul id="colors">
            <li id="white">White</li>
            <li id="green">Green</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="second-list">
        <ul id="numbers">
            <li id="one">One</li>
            <li id="two">Two</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
li{
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
}
#second-list{
  padding-left:30px;
}
```

[you can check my simple code here](http://jsfiddle.net/a8dy6/9/) .

I tried to use CSS `padding-left` to **seperate** the two list 30px away from each other, but my CSS does not work, why?

Comment: Please make sure your questions can be understood without sending users to a different site.  Very few sites can boast a perfect, 100% uptime (least of all jsFiddle).

Comment: do you want the `#fist-list` and `#second-list` to be floated to the left ?

Comment: Why don't you just use margin, that would separate them?

Comment: @Leem.fin; i know you accept the answer but did you know why that's problem arise.

Comment: @ sandeep, I dont know, that's why I have commented that I need more explainations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want the float at the li

You can float the list left, then it will work.

like this:

```
#second-list{
  padding-left:30px;
  float:left
}
```

Still I would make it another way, but I need to see what you want to achieve. Do you have a picture of it?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to have two group of horizontal tabs (that's why I need float for sure) which are made from ui li, then I would like to separate the two groups of tabs, so, my exmaple code has indicated what I want

Comment: It is also nice if you can explain the logic behind your code. Thank you.

Comment: As I did not see any good solution so far, so I picked this one...I am still looking forward to hear more

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/ it explains your problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's several problems here:

You're using Float, which destroys the layout

Div's are block-level elements, and thus will always break the line.

Simply remove the float, and make the divs inline-blocks, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8dy6/12/

good luck!

Comment: But for some reason, I need the float . How to solve the problem without remove the float.

Comment: inline-block works in pretty much EVERY browser since IE6, and IE6 has an usage share of like, 2% worldwide. It's time to let go.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to have two group of horizontal tabs (that's why I need float for sure) which are made from ui li, then I would like to separate the two groups of tabs

Comment: Why would you need float to do that? Isn't this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/6Qem8/1/

Answer (score 1):

write `overflow:hidden` in you `div` to `clear` because it `child's float`

```
div{overflow:hidden}
#second-list, #fist-list{float:left}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/a8dy6/18/

Edit: as per you comment below

```
 li{clear:left;}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/a8dy6/19/

**EDIT:**

Reason: actually  the `#second-list` takes the `padding`

if you define an element an `float` then you have to `clear` it `parent` otherwise `parent` collapse.

check this when didn't `clear the parent` http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/a8dy6/22/

So; you have to [clear](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) it's `parent` when the `child` have `float`.

check this after `clear parent` http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/a8dy6/23/

Comment: check my update & all link also. If you have any problem then ask me :)